# convert json string to xml string in iphone

Tags: iphone, xml, json, nsdictionary

I have json string came from my web service, which I stored to nsdictionary object. Now I want to convert this in xml string.
anyone have idea how can I perform this without using any external library...!?!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following links . Hope this is what you are looking for. :)

[How to convet XML string to JSON using iPhone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354159/how-to-convet-xml-string-to-json-using-iphone-sdk)

[How to convert JSON to XML in objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717669/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-objective-c)

[Automatic parsing library in objective-c - [Automated XML/JSON to Object Conversion]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124805/automatic-parsing-library-in-objective-c-automated-xml-json-to-object-convers)

Comment: Thanks but I already go through this all posts, and not find proper answer of my thing, also some links are dead in that posts...!?!

Comment: What are u looking for specifically ??

Comment: Thanks for reply Gill. Here is my situation. I have iPhone application  which call webservice and receive json data from that. I got that data properly and also success to store it in NSDictionary and work with it. Now at place I want to convert that data into xml which is right now in json format. I don't want to use any external library. Do you have any idea how I can achieve this within iOS...